# Saving users choices in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, ios7, nsuserdefaults

Hi im currently developing an app where the initial view controller is a screen with two buttons, one is for one thing and the other is for a nother thing. Each button leads to a new viewcontroller. What i want to do is for the app to recognize the users choice of button and the save that so when the user opens the app the next time it goes straight to the new viewcontroller.

I know i have to use NSUserDefaults but im pretty new to coding so if you guys could explain it it detail that would be perfect.

Thanks!

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on? Initialising it, storing values in it, getting values from it? Deciding how to store your choices?

Comment: Deciding on how to stor the choices

Answer (score 0):

When clicks the button:

```
- (void) buttonPressed: (id) sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:@"Something" forKey:@"SOME_KEY"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

}
```

You can add this code to handle what you want:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([userDefaults objectForKey:@"SOME_KEY"] != nil)
    {
        if ([[userDefaults objectForKey:@"SOME_KEY"] isEqualToString:@"Something"])
        {
            // push one ViewController
        }
        else
        {
            // push the other one
        }
    }
}
```